# error when compiling a simple maps project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, geolocation, runtime-error

im beginner for android programming.. and i want to build LBS apps on android using eclipse,, but i've got some problem. i had following so many simple tutorial to build simple google map. but it always says "unfortunately -name of apps- has stopped.

when i checked log cat. there are so many error in android runtime.
this is the log :

```
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{project.skripsi.marktogo/project.skripsi.marktogo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at project.skripsi.marktogo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    ... 11 more
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
06-17 22:01:11.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27201):    ... 21 more
```

Here my code :
mainActivity.Java

```
package project.skripsi.marktogo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    GoogleMap myMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here the layout XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="project.skripsi.marktogo.MainLayoutActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="project.skripsi.marktogo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission 
        android:name="project.skripsi.marktogo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="project.skripsi.marktogo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hasCode="true" android:persistent="true">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQUVmbzlv-hIhaTj6tayGik-NkcM9Escg"/>
        <activity
            android:name="project.skripsi.marktogo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help,, what is the problem.. i didnt understand.. sorry bad english

Comment: You are missing `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`. Also there is no need for uses library in manifest. there are few permission which are not required for map api v2. read the docs

Comment: Thanks.. for ur support ..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this declaration in your manifest:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

your code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: i already had this code in manifest : 
<meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQUVmbzlv-hIhaTj6tayGik-NkcM9Escg"/>
with that API Key..

if you mean i should add that declaration again, so the code will like :

<meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQUVmbzlv-hIhaTj6tayGik-NkcM9Escg"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
is that true?

Comment: great! You can accept the answer to close your question